# DHCP failing to update DNS, no Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp

I have a DHCP and DNS server, running Windows 2003 SP1. I configure everything according to [this Microsoft Technet article "Using DNS servers with DHCP"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787034(WS.10).aspx), but it does not work. Note that the client is a Linux client, but that should not matter; it did not work when it sent option 81 or when it only sent a hostname.

Also note the following documents/tutorials that we read:

- [How to Enable DHCP and automatic DNS update for non-Windows (Linux, FreeBSD) clients in Win server 2003](http://www.windowsreference.com/dns/how-to-enable-dhcp-and-automatic-dns-update-for-non-windows-linuxfreebsd-clients-in-win-server-2003/)
- [How to configure DNS dynamic updates in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816592)
- [How do I... Configure DHCP for dynamic updates in Windows Server 2008?](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=377)

In the logs I get the following messages:

```
30,07/10/09,16:31:04,DNS Update Request,151.28.30.10,hostname.testdomain.local,,MACHINE-317A15D\Administrator
31,07/10/09,16:31:51,DNS Update Failed,10.30.28.151,hostname.testdomain.local,2,
30,07/10/09,16:31:51,DNS Update Request,151.28.30.10,hostname.testdomain.local,,
10,07/10/09,16:31:51,Assign,10.30.28.151,hostname.testdomain.local,001D09117758,
31,07/10/09,16:46:08,DNS Update Failed,10.30.28.151,hostname.testdomain.local,-1,
```

One other clue I have is the following event log entry:
[image: Event Properties]

with the following text:

> The DNS server machine currently has
>   no DNS domain name.  Its DNS name is a
>   single label hostname with no domain
>   (example:  "host" rather than
>   "host.microsoft.com").
>
> You might have forgotten to configure a primary DNS domain for the
>   server computer. For more information,
>   see either "DNS server log reference"
>   or "To configure the primary DNS
>   suffix for a client computer" in the
>   online Help.
>
> While the DNS server has only a single label name, all zones created
>   will have default records (SOA and NS)
>   created using only this single label
>   name for the server's hostname.  This
>   can lead to incorrect and failed
>   referrals when clients and other DNS
>   servers use these records to locate
>   this server by name.
>
> To correct this problem:
>   1) open Control Panel
>   2) open System applet
>   3) select Computer Name tab
>   4) click the "Change" button and join the computer to a domain or workgroup; this name will be used as your DNS domain name
>   5) reboot to initialize with new domain name
>
> After reboot, the DNS server will attempt to fix up default
>   records, substituting new DNS name of
>   this server, for old single label
>   name.  However, you should review to
>   make sure zone's SOA and NS records
>   now properly use correct domain name
>   of this server
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

This question is almost identical to [this earlier ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/34553/dhcp-failing-to-update-dns), except that in this case the DHCP/DNS server are not joined to an ActiveDirectory domain. Also it is different from [this other ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/36332/dhcp-not-actually-updating-dns-even-though-logs-indicate-otherwise), because in my case the logs do indicate a failure, not success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. As the Event log states, you must join a domain for this to work. The Active Directory domain name is used as the DNS domain name for the system.

As soon as we recreated the configuration with the DHCP/DNS server joined to Active Directory, it all worked.